# É possivel pesquisar no SQL server todas as tabelas do banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Gostaria de Saber se no SQL Server eu consigo pesquisar no banco de dados o nome de todas as tabelas, e a quantidade de registros que cada uma tem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível. Basta usar [objetos do sistema](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), como o [sys.partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), mas lembre-se que ele informa apenas um **número aproximado de linhas**. Para ter certeza, você precisa conferir com o `COUNT`.

Considere o script abaixo:

```
SELECT
    s.Name [Schema],
    t.Name [TableName],
    p.[Rows] 
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.object_id 
GROUP BY s.Name, t.NAME, p.[Rows] 
ORDER BY p.[Rows] DESC
```

Resultado:

| Schema | TableName | Rows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dbo | TabelaX | 500 |
| dbo | TabelaY | 133 |

Como não especificou a versão do SQL Server utilizado, considerei a versão mais recente disponível na documentação.

Answer (score -2):

Pra saber a quantidade de registros que cada tabela tem, você pode usar a função de agregação COUNT, ela retorna a quantidade total de valores de uma coluna. Ex.:

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Clientes**

Agora pra retornar todas as tabelas, que eu saiba não existe nenhum comando que possibilite isso, mas tem como usar UNION/UNION ALL e fazer umas gambiarra. Porém daria bastante trabalho, pq as tabelas precisam ter o mesmo número de expressões e os tipos de dados precisam combinar, então teria que atribuir um valor nulo pras tabelas q sobrarem, e teria que usar CONVERT(VARCHAR, Coluna) pra converter os tipos de dados que não batem

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).